# Firebase autenticación con dominios personalizados

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Tengo una app que estoy desarrollando. La autenticación funciona correctamente en el dominio predetrminado que ofrece firebase al inicio. He añadido un dominio personalizado recientemente y ha dejado de funcionar la autenticación. Ya he cambiado la URL en React que redirige la App al nuevo dominio, pero sigue sin funcionar. No entra con google ni envía emails de confirmación para entrar. ¿debo cambiar algo más en el código?. Cuando entro con la url antigua prederterminada, el login sigue funcionando correctamente. Es decir, el dominio nuevo parece que solo aloja y muestra a App, pero no funciona la autenticación.

Gracias por vuestras ideas o sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate de haber añadido tu dominio personalizado en la configuración de sign-in method de firebase en la parte de

Dominios autorizados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te ayude, caso contrario estare atento a tus comentarios ;)